# How to mock a generic parameter for a unit test in Java?

Tags: java, generics, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a function signature I'd like to mock of an External Service.

```
public <T> void save(T item, AnotherClass anotherClassObject);
```

Given this function signature, and class name `IGenericService` how could one mock it with PowerMock? 
Or Mockito?

For this generic, I'm using: Class `Theodore` for the T in `T item`. For example, I tried using:

```
doNothing().when(iGenericServiceMock.save(any(Theodore.class),
                    any(AnotherClass.class));
```

IntelliJ cranks this:

```
save(T, AnotherClass) cannot be applied to 
(org.Hamcrest.Matcher<Theodore>, org.Hamcrest.Matcher<AnotherClass>)
```

And it cites the following reason:

```
reason: No instance(s) of type variable T exist 
so that Matcher<T> conforms to AnotherClass
```

First, the issue ought to solve if the generics argument is handled properly. What are some things one could do in such situations?

UPDATE: As ETO shared:

```
doNothing().when(mockedObject).methodToMock(argMatcher);
```

shares the same fate.

Comment: Please can you add the code you are trying in a code block (indent by 4). It's hard to see what you are saying.

Comment: Are you able to change the signature of the `save` method? The `T` isn't actually doing anything useful there; you may as well just use `Object` instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner Actually the interface is quite valid. It's a DynamoDBService interface. Item represents the DAO object for a table name in the DB.

Comment: It may be valid, it's just pointless to have a type variable there.

Comment: It does seem pointless out of context. It's implementation would not accept an Object if you think about it though. For instance, to pass an Object instead of DAOTableName.java isn't pragmatic when you consider how DynamoDBMapper accepts input parameters. The Generic helps resolve the DB table from the item name itself. So. I could be wrong, I don't know. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing wrong parameters to `when`. It may be a bit confusing, but there are two different usages of `when` method (actually those are two different methods):

1. ```
   when(mockedObject.methodYouWantToMock(expectedParameter, orYourMatcher)).thenReturn(objectToReturn);
   ```
2. ```
   doReturn(objectToReturn).when(mockedObject).methodYouWantToMock(expectedParameter, orYourMatcher);
   ```

*Note: pay attention to input parameters of `when` method in both cases*.

In your particular case you could do something like this:

```
doReturn(null).when(iGenericServiceMock).save(any(Theodore.class), any(AnotherClass.class));
```

This will fix your compilation issues. However the test will fail at runtime with `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue` because you are trying to return something from a `void` method (`null` is not `void`). What you should do is :

```
doNothing().when(iGenericServiceMock).save(any(Theodore.class), any(AnotherClass.class));
```

Later you can check the interactions with your mock using `verify` method.

UPDATE:

Check your imports. You should use `org.mockito.Matchers.any` instead of `org.hamcrest.Matchers.any`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out! I was so fizzled with this, actually I implemented doNothing().when(mockedObject).methodIWantToMock(anyMatcher, anyMatcher) exactly as your answer's last code snippet. Intellij still cranks on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Helpful, nonetheless!

Comment: Check your imports. You should use `org.mockito.Matchers.any` instead of `org.hamcrest.Matchers.any`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Mockito's `ArgumentMatcher`. Also in `when` put only the mock's reference:

```
doReturn(null).when(iGenericServiceMock).save(
    ArgumentMatchers.<Theodore>any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(AnotherClass.class));
```

Comment: I tried to see where this answer's implementation would take the code. My library does not yet have ArgumentMatchers. It does have ArgumentMatcher, but I checked and they are so so not same.

Comment: You may need to use Matchers class in that case

Answer (score 1):

Great and swift answers! I finally got it to smooth over with the following code:

```
doNothing().when(iGenericServiceMock).save(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

it wasn't until I prepended Mockito to the any method that Intellij became joyful about it again.